# How to use sjplot in R function plot_grpfrq in a "facet grid" way based on another variable

Tags: r, plot, sjplot

I have three variables in my data frame. A, B and C. I am interested in the relative frequency of C given combinations of A & B.

My dataset using dput:

```
structure(list(B = structure(c(1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("text1", 
"text2", "text3"), class = "factor"), A = structure(c(3L, 
4L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 3L), .Label = c("Control_base", "Control_info", 
"TreatA", "TreatB"), class = "factor"), , C = structure(c(1, 
0, 2, 3, 2, 3), format.stata = "%9.0g", labels = c(somea = 0, 
someb = 1, somec = 2, somed = 3), class = c("haven_labelled", "vctrs_vctr", 
"double"))), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

I want to use sjplot plot_grpfrq however, I would want 4 plots (for my four categories of B). However this code does not work:

```
data %>% group_by(B) %>% 
 plot_grpfrq(
    var.cnt = data$A, 
    var.grp = data$C) %>%
  plot_grid()
```

Giving the error: Error in match.arg(type) : 'arg' must be NULL or a character vector

This code works:

```
plot_grpfrq(
    var.cnt = data$A, 
    var.grp = data$C)
```

These codes also work:

```
data %>% group_by(B) %>% 
  plot_frq(C) %>%
  plot_grid()
```

and

```
data %>% group_by(A) %>% 
  plot_frq(C) %>%
  plot_grid()
```

Is there anything I am missing here?

Comment: could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: thank you, I did. Sorry it looks so weird. No idea why.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `group_map` to generate a list with a plot for each group, so that it can be processed by `plot_grid`:

```
library(dplyr)
data %>% group_by(B) %>%
         group_map(~plot_grpfrq(var.cnt = .x$A,
                                var.grp = .x$C)) %>%
         plot_grid()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that is very helpful. I am just curious, do you also get the Warning: In plot_grid(.) : Not enough tags labels in list. Using letters instead. Because actually instead of As and A/B/C there should be my labels and they don't show. (however if I change B with .x$A for example, I do indeed see the labels, however the three (or 4) subplots are always just getting A/B/C/(D)

Comment: I should say, replacing plot_grid() with plot_grid(, label = c("label1", "label2", "label3")) does not work because of unused argument

Comment: Sadly, it also just don't work for me @Waldi because it always gives me all data so each plot looks 100% the same content wise =(